# On click image becomes larger and transferring to Landing page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I saw very cool effect on this website https://www.humaan.com/work/
When you click on image, image increasing and turns to landing page.
How this effect calls and how to get it?
I was unlucky trying to find any code examples.
Will be thankful for any thoughts.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could just be some fancy css, a few google searches brought me to this page [19 amazing css transitions](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/css-page-transitions/) and the effects in numbers 3, and 11 look pretty similar to what your trying to achieve. The code for these effects is also displayed on the page beside the examples.

Edit: There is also some JS involved in most of these effects, don't forget to click on the JS tab in the examples!

Comment: Thank you, now I one step closer to the solution :) But still do not understand how to avoid 'blinking' effect when URL changing. I mean, when I click on image, it's increasing to the full page size, but at the moment when page switching to a new URL there still a moment when you can see transferring from one page to another.

Comment: You will likely need to write some javascript that helps create "smooth page transitions"